# Как добавить переход по ссылке в Express (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Есть "сайт" дневник, где человек пишет свои дела, и текст каждой заметки обрезается после 100 символов, а рядом стоит ссылка **Read more**, так вот, нужно чтобы при нажатии на **read more**, определенной заметки, express перенаправлял на post.ejs с полным текстом. Страницы написаны на ejs.
Статическая ссылка через `<a href="post.ejs">` вряд ли пойдет.
[image: Пример сайта]

```
    <%- include("partials/header"); -%>

    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p><%= startingContent %></p>

    <% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
        <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
        <p><%= post.content.substring(0, 100) + '... '  %><a>Read more</a></p>

    <% }) %>


<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

P.S. При необходимости могу приложить так же код сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ссылке должен быть id поста, что-то типа `<a href="/post/<%= post.id %>">`.

На сервере обработчик, что-то типа:

```
app.get('/post/:id', function(req, res) {
    const id = req.params.id
```

Там берем содержимое поста по id, и возвращаем клиенту, используя "post.ejs".

Comment: Я вчера решил эту проблему, и Ваше решение правильное, благодарю!